# How to get either all documents of a projection or only one?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents that look like:

```
{
    "_id": xxxx,
    "user_id1": "1234",
    "user_id2": "2345",
    "amount": 30000,
    "code": "ABC1",
    "date_processed": datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11),
    ...
}
```

and I am summing up amounts for a given timeframe if they have the same `code` field. Here's what that looks like:

```
cursor = db.aggregate([
    {"$match": {"user_id1": 1234, "code": "ABC1"}},
    {"$project": {
        "day" {"$cond": [{"$gte": ["$date_processed, datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1), "$amount", 0]},
        "month" {"$cond": [{"$gte": ["$date_processed, datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30), "$amount", 0]},
        "year" {"$cond": [{"$gte": ["$date_processed, datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=365), "$amount", 0]},
    }},
    {"$group": {
        "_id": 1,
        "day": {"$sum": "$day"},
        "month": {"$sum": "$month"},
        "year": {"$sum": "$year"}
    }}
])
```

**My question is**: sometimes `user_id1` and `user_id2` can be the same value, and in this case *I would like to filter out all of them except the first occurrence*. Is this possible? I've looked at every operation in the `aggregate()` documentation and it doesn't seem like there is a straightforward pipeline for this. My current path is to try:

```
{"$match": {"$user_id1": 1234, "code": "ABC1"}},
{"$group": {"_id": "$user_id2", "matches": {"$push": {"$eq": ["user_id1", "user_id2"]}}}},
...
```

and this seems promising since I'm now getting a lists of booleans, all of which are either `True` when the ids match, or completely `False` when they don't. I can then peek at these using `"$arrayElemAt"` inside a projection, but I'm not sure how to branch into taking the whole array (when `False`) or just the first element (when `True`).

Just in case this isn't clear enough, the reason for filtering is that when `user_id1` and `user_id2` are the same, then the documents are duplicates (they are in the db this way by design) and I'd like to avoid summing over these particular duplicate documents. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: sometimes user_id1 and user_id2 can be the same value,
>   and in this case I would like to filter out all of them except the
>   first occurrence. Is this possible?

The following two steps of the aggregation will remove the duplicate occurrences of documents where `user_id1` and `user_id2` are same values. The resulting data set will have a documents without the duplicates.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { 
      $group: {
           _id: { user_id1: "$user_id1", user_id2: "$user_id2" }, 
           doc: { $first: "$$ROOT"  } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$doc" } 
  }
] )
```

---

[ EDIT ADD ]

For input documents:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eba05c892367c3459d4e6f4"),
        "user_id1" : "1234",
        "user_id2" : "2345",
        "amount" : 300,
        "code" : "ABC1"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eba05c892367c3459d4e6f5"),
        "user_id1" : "1234",
        "user_id2" : "6789",
        "amount" : 400,
        "code" : "DEF1"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eba05c892367c3459d4e6f6"),
        "user_id1" : "999",
        "user_id2" : "999",
        "amount" : 900,
        "code" : "XYZ1"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eba05c892367c3459d4e6f7"),
        "user_id1" : "999",
        "user_id2" : "999",
        "amount" : 900,
        "code" : "XYZ1"
}
```

The output is:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eba05c892367c3459d4e6f6"),
        "user_id1" : "999",
        "user_id2" : "999",
        "amount" : 900,
        "code" : "XYZ1"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eba05c892367c3459d4e6f5"),
        "user_id1" : "1234",
        "user_id2" : "6789",
        "amount" : 400,
        "code" : "DEF1"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eba05c892367c3459d4e6f4"),
        "user_id1" : "1234",
        "user_id2" : "2345",
        "amount" : 300,
        "code" : "ABC1"
}
```

Comment: Nice! However, this looks like it also replaces documents where `user_id1` and `user_id2` are different and I'd like to keep those untouched. Maybe I could `switch` depending on whether or not the ids are the same.

Comment: I just added some sample documents - with before and after the aggregation stages I had posted.  If you want to process only some documents with a condition, you can use the `$match` stage to filter. For example, the stage `{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$user_id1", "$user_id2" ] } } }`, will filter only documents which have same values for `user_id1` and `user_id2` fields. You can place this stage in the pipeline as the first stage of the aggregation.

Comment: Oh nice, I see now! Thanks!